# Need to create listener for docker plugin on Jenkins on port 2375

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use the following docker command to create a jenkins container server along with enabling the docker api for the docker plugin.

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -d -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 jenkins
```

Unfortunately i am getting the below error message which indicates the `-H` flag isn't allowed on docker run

```
 `unknown shorthand flag: 'H' in -H
  See 'docker run --help'.`
```

Any ideas on what to do in order to create this listener?

Comment: try putting `docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -d -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins`

Comment: `docker --help` shws among other things `-H, --host=[]                   Daemon socket(s) to connect to`